# regex. How to return smaller result

Tags: regex

I have this regex `in[^\s]`. It captures any three characters sequence, which has "in" and any character but space.

Results for test cases:

```
integer     -> int
inline      -> inl
instruction -> ins
in          -> "nothing"
```

Now what I want is that this regex would consider, that third character is not empty space, but won't mark third character

I want it to work like this:

```
integer     -> in
inline      -> in
instruction -> in
in          -> "nothing"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead for this:

```
in(?=\S)
```

`(?=\S)` is a positive lookahead that makes sure `in` is followed by a non-space.

`\S` is same as `[^\s]`.

Also better you use word boundary to avoid matching `in` in the middle of a word:

```
\bin(?=\S)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dT5gW8/6)